# Microsoft.AspNet.Identity - What data should be stored as an identity claim vs another database table

Tags: claims-based-identity, claims

What would be best practice to determine what I should store in the identity claim object versus in a separate table. For example, let's say that each user needs to have access to multiple sites. See object below:

```
public class Site
{
    public int SiteID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } 

    public string Url { get; set; } 
}
```

Should i store the Site object as a Serialized Claim or should I create database table for it, as well make the Site object a property of the Application User class of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity framework.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public Site[] Sites {get; set;}

}
```